# Except table with a conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have two tables, id is primary key

```
Old
{
 id
 name
 school
 ...
 version
}

New
{
 id
 name
 school
 ...
 version
}
```

i want to find same id in both table have same key, but different other columns and ignore the version.

```
Select * From [New] n Inner Join On [Old] o On n.id = o.id
Where n.name != o.name OR n.school!=o.school ....(Do all the columns without version)
```

that is works, but there are actually a lot of columns, can i do it with Except?

```
SELECT * FROM [New] WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM [New] EXCEPT (SELECT id FROM [Old]))
```

this is Except version, but this one did not consider that WE NEED TO IGNORE THE VERSION COLUMN.

Comment: was on -1 ....just changed it back to 0 as this question is useful

Comment: 3:Questions, 0:Accepted answers. You should start to accept answers. Gordon Linoff's answer has six upvotes. Why this answer is not accepted ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the framework for the solution:

```
  select <columnlist>
  from new
  where id in (select id from old)
  except 
  select <columnlist>
  from old
```

To get `<columnlist>`, you can type it in manually.  Or, you can query from `information_schema.columns`.  Or, you can go into SQL Server Management studio and do the following:

- Open the database in the Object Explorer
- Open "Tables"
- Open the table of interest (`New`)
- Click on "Columns" (no need to open it) and drag it into a query window

All the columns appear.  Then delete the `version` that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Old TABLE (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Col1 INT NULL,
    Col2 VARCHAR(50) NULL
);
DECLARE @New TABLE (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Col1 INT NULL,
    Col2 VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

INSERT  @Old (Id, Col1, Col2)
SELECT 1, 11, 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 22, 'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 33, 'C'
UNION ALL SELECT 4, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, NULL, NULL;

INSERT  @New (Id, Col1, Col2)
SELECT 1, 11, 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 222, 'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, NULL, 'C'
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 44, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, NULL, NULL;

PRINT 'Begin of test';

PRINT '@Old:';
SELECT * FROM @Old;

PRINT '@New:';
SELECT * FROM @New;

PRINT 'Last SELECT:'
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT  x.Id, x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Rowtype,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Id ORDER BY x.Col1, x.Col2) AS Rnk1,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Id ORDER BY x.Col1 DESC, x.Col2 DESC) AS Rnk2
    FROM (
        SELECT  o.Id, o.Col1, o.Col2, 1 AS RowType
        FROM    @Old o
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  n.Id, n.Col1, n.Col2, 2 AS RowType
        FROM    @New n
    ) x
) y
--WHERE y.RowType=1 AND (y.Rnk1=2 OR y.Rnk2=2) -- Only old rows
WHERE   y.RowType=2 AND (y.Rnk1=2 OR y.Rnk2=2) -- Only new rows

PRINT 'End of test';
```

Results:

```
Id Col1 Col2 Rowtype Rnk1 Rnk2
-- ---- ---- ------- ---- ----
2  222  B    2       2    1
3  NULL C    2       1    2
4  44   NULL 2       2    1
```

Messages:

```
Begin of test
@Old:
Table '#671F4F74'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2
@New:
Table '#6AEFE058'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2
Last SELECT:
Table '#6AEFE058'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2
Table '#671F4F74'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2
End of test
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure why I doubted it!) but I couldn't visualize Gordon's answer.

I set up the following example to prove it to myself:

```
CREATE TABLE #old (id INT,y INT,z INT);
INSERT INTO #old
    values
    (1,2,3),
    (2,3,4),
    (5,6,7),
    (8,9,10);

CREATE TABLE #new (id INT,y INT,z INT);
INSERT INTO #new
    values
    (1,2,3),
    (2,30,4),
    (5,6,7),
    (8,9,100);

--Existing script
SELECT n.id, n.y, n.z
FROM #new n
    INNER JOIN #old o
    ON n.id = o.id
WHERE
    n.y != o.y
    OR
    n.z != o.z;

--Gordon's answer
SELECT id, y, z
FROM #new
WHERE id IN (SELECT id from #old)
EXCEPT 
SELECT id, y, z
FROM #old;
```